# How to create Error message in above two <td>

Tags: html

There are two  in my project

Name: Text Box

whenever user click on submit button without entering any thing then the error message should come above of those two

Plz Help me two solve it

Comment: Can you post the HTML you have so far?

Comment: No, I wasn't post html so far

Comment: Use Jquery validation.

Comment: I don't know Jquery, is it possible in HTML itself

Comment: you can use input required for each input which cannot be left empy,

Comment: If you can't post the HTML, there's not a huge amount we can do to help.

Comment: May i know your html ?

Answer (score 1):

```
  if(empty($_POST['submit']))
    {
       echo "please fill the detail";

    }
  else
   {
     echo "you are done";
   }
 place the code above the two you want.
 This code is in php. you need to make php file for this. and to run this you need WAMP server. localhost
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of HTML5 validation which is supported in most modern browsers. More information can be found here:

http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/

If you want styled error messages on custom positions you will have to move to jQuery and plugins that handle validation. For example:

https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine